# Duplicate div without duplicate input[type=range]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to Duplicate this comparison But without duplicate the input[type=range] in CSS, Divisor class and JavaScript code
because I will create more than 50 comparison if I duplicate CSS and JavaScript code I will not get a best performance code

```
<div id="comparison">
  <figure>
    <div id="divisor"></div>
  </figure>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="slider" oninput="moveDivisor()">
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
input[type=range]{
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  position: relative;
  top: -2rem; left: -2%;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  width: 102%; 
}
input[type=range]:focus { 
  outline: none; 
}
input[type=range]:active { 
  outline: none;  
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
var divisor = document.getElementById("divisor"),
slider = document.getElementById("slider");
function moveDivisor() { 
    divisor.style.width = slider.value+"%";
}
```

Comment: _"without duplicate the input[type=range] in CSS"_ - Why you think you have to duplicate anything related to the style? The selectors match _every_ input element of type range in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to add new comparison instances to a DOM element - or if none given to document.body.
It's pure JS code, no HTML needed. 
If you want to add comparison to `<div id='container'></div>` call `addComparison(document.getElementById('container'))`. 
Your CSS code will work for the generated comparison instances. If you need to use any classes or ids just add them to the desired element, like: 
`divisor.id = 'divisor'` or `divisor.className = 'divisor'`

```
function addComparison(el) {
    var target = el || document.body;
    var comparison = document.createElement('div');
    var figure = document.createElement('figure');
    var divisor = document.createElement('div');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'range';
    input.min = '0';
    input.max = '100';
    input.value = '50';
    input.oninput = function() {
        divisor.style.width = this.value + '%';
    }
    figure.appendChild(divisor);
    comparison.appendChild(figure);
    comparison.appendChild(input);
    target.appendChild(comparison);
}
```

Comment: Use a class instead of numerated ids. That's what they are made for.